# How do you set the extent of a CartoDB 'embed' map?

Tags: carto, wordpress

Using the basic CartoDB 'embed' option, how is the extent stored / saved / set for a map?

For example:

A CartoDB map (formerly 'visualization') has three potential pages on my blog / website (WordPress) for each State I want to show from my map.

I can't seem to figure out how to use the same 'map' for 3 different extents (views) of the same map.

There is no option to set the extent, and it seems to be set to the last place you panned/zoomed to on the map itself - with no option to save.

Am I missing something or is there a better workflow for this?

And since I'm using WordPress, I can't use CartoDB.js, and the same problem seems to apply to using the 'simple link' for the WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters (center_lat, center_lon and zoom( in the URL of the embed map in order to set up the center and the level of zoom, for example:

```
https://team.cartodb.com/u/iriberri/viz/898df9fe-fed8-11e4-a88e-0e853d047bba/embed_map?center_lat=0&center_lon=0&zoom=2
```

You can find also the same information in our documentation [here](https://carto.com/help/tutorials/editor-faqs-sharing-maps/#how-can-i-set-the-position-of-an-embedded-map)

Comment: Ok I see that's in there - would be nice to have it exposed in the embed window as this isn't really intuitive (embedding being the most basic form of using a cartodb map...) Thanks!!!